# Why doesn't the command "php bin/console make:user" work?

Tags: php, symfony

I am following the guide [Symfony Security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html.)

And when I type **`php bin/console make:user`** I get this error:

```
Command "make:user" is not defined.
                                    
Did you mean one of these?
    make: admin: crud
    make: admin: dashboard
    make: admin: migration
```

Comment: Probably you are trying to `make:user` in `prod` environment.
Switching from `prod` to `dev` environment in your project `.env` root file could solve your problem.
-- Maurice

Comment: @diam, in my case it was that I needed to have MakeBundle installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to install the MakeBundle with:

**"composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev"**

Answer (score 2):

First of all please be sure that you have both the maker bundle and the security bundle installed. Just to be sure run both:

```
composer require symfony/security-bundle
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
```

If the error still persists please run php bin/console make:user -vvv to see the stack trace.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/verbosity.html